# How do I assign the value of a checkbox to a razor variable?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

How can i get the value of  checkbox value of `showHideDeletedRps` in a variable? I have the following code in my view I used dependency injection to populate fields in a view but i like to get the value of checkbox to pass it with `GetRPByID()` method. Is it possible to accomplish that in asp.net core?

Here is my code in razor view

```
@{
    var showDeleted = get_showDeletedRpValue // I like to get the checkbox value here 
    var id = Model.ID;
    var rpInfo = await rpService.GetRPByID(id, showDeleted);
}
   <div class="card">
       <input name="showHideDeletedRps" id="showHideDeletedRps" type="checkbox" value="true">
   </div>
```

[image]

Code added

```
@{    
 var showDeleted = true; // or false, depends on what you want to be default
  if (Context.Request.Form.TryGetValue("showHideDeletedRps", out var formValue) && 
    bool.TryParse(formValue, out var value))
  {
      showDeleted = value;
  } 
   
}
```

Comment: Are you using MVC or Razor page with code-behind? In both cases, you should bind check-box value to a model.

Comment: @RoarS. yes but i am using view component for this page I cant use `@model` in this view, i have used -@model in the main view this one is view component

Comment: Then you may have a problem with your design. Can you provide us with complete code, both controller and all Razor views?

Comment: What happens if you use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.showHideDeletedRps)`

Comment: @VDWWD: In this code, the only place check-box value will change, is on client-side. Rendering happens on server-side.

Comment: @RoarS. I know. Using `CheckBoxFor` will immediatelty show it `showHideDeletedRps` is present in the model. Otherwise you will see an error message in VS.

Comment: Posted a solution for reading check-box value from the request.

Comment: Thanks @RoarS. i  added a screenshot of what i get it weird i couldn't find where the issue coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that supports either form data or query string

```
@{
    var showDeleted = true; // or false, depends on what you want to be default
    if (Context.Request.HasFormContentType && Context.Request.Form.TryGetValue("showHideDeletedRps", out var formValue)
        && bool.TryParse(formValue, out var parsedFormValue))
    {
        showDeleted = parsedFormValue;
    }
    else if (Context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("showHideDeletedRps", out var queryValue)
        && bool.TryParse(queryValue, out var parsedQueryValue))
    {
        showDeleted = parsedQueryValue;
    }
}
```

For autopostback, put this script at the bottom of your page (make sure jQuery is included before this script). Works with checkboxes, radiobuttons and selects.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select[autopostback=true],input[type=checkbox][autopostback=true],input[type=radio][autopostback=true]").on("change", function () {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
</script>
```

and change checkbox like this

```
<input autopostback="true" name="showHideDeletedRps" id="showHideDeletedRps" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220061/discussion-on-answer-by-roar-s-how-do-i-assign-the-value-of-a-checkbox-to-a-raz).